# what can i use the candy box for

Tags: candy-box-2

So I opened the candy box and went to the tab but I cant figure out how to get the infinite sweets I tried clicking on them as they fell by  and also I got all the stones and everthing I beat the developer devil and that stuff so how do I do this?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out I don't need any help

Comment: Perhaps you could post the solution to your problem?

Comment: answer your own question. Many others might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the computer and type "add [amount] [item]"

For example:

add 10000 candies

add 1000000 lollipops

(Answered for other people that might need help)